# How to get td value on post php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<form action="" method="post" name="theform">
    <table width="693" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed;" >
    <tr>
    <td width="683" id="mymessage" contenteditable="true" name="mymessage">Write message here...</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <span class="notranslate"><input type="submit" id="btnSend" name="btnSend" value="Send"></span>
    </form>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['btnSend']))
    {
        $getmsg = $_POST['mymessage'];//i can't seem to get the value of td here
        echo $getmsg;//i want to echo the message for example.
    }
    ?>
```

Currently, I want to echo my td value after clicking the button but it is not appearing. please help me. tq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `contenteditable` is not part of `form input` element hence it can not be accessed over server like `form-input-elements`. It means you can not access `contenteditable` element value in `$_POST`/`$_GET`

Update `hidden` field value when value of `contenteditable` is changed. use `input` event. *The `DOM input` event is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element is changed. Additionally, it fires on `contenteditable` editors when its contents are changed.*

```js
document.getElementById('mymessage').addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.getElementById('hiddenInput').value = this.innerHTML;
  console.log(document.getElementById('hiddenInput').value);
});
document.getElementById('hiddenInput').value = document.getElementById('mymessage').innerHTML; //To set the value initially..
console.log(document.getElementById('hiddenInput').value);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" name="theform">
  <table width="693" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr>
      <td width="683" id="mymessage" contenteditable="true" name="mymessage">Write message here...</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" id='hiddenInput' name='hiddenInput'>
  <span class="notranslate"><input type="submit" id="btnSend" name="btnSend" value="Send"></span>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnSend']))
{
    $getmsg = $_POST['hiddenInput'];
    echo $getmsg;
}
?>
```

**Edit:** As [*Nate*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2609094/nate) pointed out, It is better to use `submit` or `click`(If not dealing with `form`) event to set the value of the `hidden` element for the sake of the *performance*

```js
document.querySelector('[name="theform"]').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //Prevented submit action just to demonstrate..
  document.getElementById('hiddenInput').value = document.getElementById('mymessage').innerHTML;
  console.log(document.getElementById('hiddenInput').value);
})
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" name="theform">
  <table width="693" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr>
      <td width="683" id="mymessage" contenteditable="true" name="mymessage">Write message here...</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" id='hiddenInput' name='hiddenInput'>
  <span class="notranslate"><input type="submit" id="btnSend" name="btnSend" value="Send"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Inspect element..Check the value of  `hiddenInput`

Comment: its working fine now. just placed the script at the wrong place. but if i did not edit the text, it wont echo. what should i do?

Comment: Check the console for errors...Your script tag should be before closing `body` tag...

Comment: it;s working. thanks. but if i did not edit the text and just clicked the button, it will not echo the "Write message here..." text. what shouls i do to allow that to appear as well?

Comment: hi. why does it delete the final text? for example, if i type "test" inside, it will only echo "tes". what is wrong?

Comment: Note that for the sake of efficiency, you should not be updating the hidden attribute using the `input` event. Particularly if your contenteditable is going to be handling fairly large data. `input` is fired for every single keystroke, so if you type "hello" the event is fired off 6 times. This is a lot of wasted swapping of value of the hidden input. Instead you should simply put a `submit` event on the `form` element and set the value of the hidden input at that single time when the user is submitting their work.

Comment: ok it's working well after the updated snippet. thank you very much :)

Comment: Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Answer (score 0):

`td` is not form element so it does not have such attributes as `name` or `value`. You can put that value to hidden field or text field:

```css
input {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<table width="693" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed;">
  <tr>
    <td width="683" contenteditable="true">
      <input id="mymessage" type="text" value="Write message here..." name="mymessage" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Other option would be to use jQuery to get content of td:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: {
            mymessage: $('#mymessage').text()
        },
        success: function () {
            // do something on success
        }
    });

    return false; // return false so that form will not submit reloading page. Form submitting is now done via Ajax
});
```